# Python remove range lines from csv inc structure of database

Tags: python, database, line

I Would like to remove range lines: 15 - 405061, but i would like to have structure of my CSV Database file. My Script (below) is fully working, but after executing this script, my structure of file is damaged.

Database before removing line:
[image: Befor removing lines]

After removing using python script:
[image]

The Example CSV File:

```
"Rec No","Guid","Recordnumber","Site","Cardnumber","Empnumber","Date","Time","Device","Direction","Type","Status","Deleted","User","Accessdata","Jobdata","Originaldate","Originaltime","Originaldirection","Company","Branch","Department","Costcenter","Category","Scale","Emptype","Workgroup","Job","Quantity","Jobdata1","Clo:comment"
13,"Here}WR@tdLKTYDf",0,"Here","2012      ","2012      ",75261,2932601,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
16,"Here}WR@[^VKdpB[",0,"Here","6224      ","6224      ",75261,2973401,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
17,"Here}WR@LLZKsWzJ",0,"Here","6074      ","6074      ",75261,2988601,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
18,"Here}WR@Do^Kc~DC",0,"Here","6241      ","6241      ",75261,3008001,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
20,"Here}WR@tzdKHAbS",0,"Here","6107      ","6107      ",75261,3033001,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
28,"Here}WR@OSsK}]ID",0,"Here","6011      ","6011      ",75261,3092201,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
30,"Here}WR@NZwKHFJU",0,"Here","7000      ","7000      ",75261,3109201,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
34,"Here}WR@yp|KzRFh",0,"Here","2014      ","2014      ",75261,3130001,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
39,"Here}WR@y\GLDT]v",0,"Here","9998      ","~Invalid  ",75261,3175601,"A       "," "," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
40,"Here}WR@UeKLEKFp",0,"Here","6229      ","6229      ",75261,3191001,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
56,"Here}WR@][oLKJXg",0,"Here","6229      ","6229      ",75261,3339201,"A       ","O"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
57,"Here}WR@ePpLXhOS",0,"Here","6229      ","6229      ",75261,3343201,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
61,"Here}WR@Gs{LQbhq",0,"Here","7017      ","7017      ",75261,3388201,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
62,"Here}WR@lv}LObFx",0,"Here","1067      ","1067      ",75261,3396801,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
73,"Here}WR@{[mMzwPx",0,"Here","7018      ","7018      ",75261,3591001,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
74,"Here}WR@bvmMKH~h",0,"Here","9998      ","~Invalid  ",75261,3593601,"A       "," "," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
81,"Here}WR@[gFNbCR`",0,"Here","9998      ","~Invalid  ",75261,3695601,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
92,"Here}WR@JPnNVM|o",0,"Here","9998      ","~Invalid  ",75261,3858201,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
97,"Here}WR@c|xNw~uy",0,"Here","1306      ","1306      ",75261,3897601,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
98,"Here}WR@MWyNYTfQ",0,"Here","9998      ","~Invalid  ",75261,3899601,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
103,"Here}WR@hcAOqZx|",0,"Here","1050      ","1050      ",75261,3928601,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
114,"Here}WR@hk|PxNDF",0,"Here","6011      ","6011      ",75261,4441401,"A       ","O"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
115,"Here}WR@}tNSdWws",0,"Here","6229      ","6229      ",75261,5041201,"A       ","O"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
123,"Here}WR@vw~SSPsg",0,"Here","2014      ","2014      ",75261,5236601,"A       ","O"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
124,"Here}WR@_RSnah",0,"Here","6241      ","6241      ",75261,5238201,"A       ","O"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
141,"Here}WR@fMITokJC",0,"Here","6074      ","6074      ",75261,5280401,"A       ","O"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
142,"Here}WR@oBJT|FtK",0,"Here","1067      ","1067      ",75261,5283201,"A       ","O"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
145,"Here}WR@n`LTnfnJ",0,"Here","9998      ","~Invalid  ",75261,5292801,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
147,"Here}WR@yQRTx||x",0,"Here","1449      ","1449      ",75261,5314601,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
167,"Here}WR@\soUZ`R",0,"Here","9998      ","~Invalid  ",75261,5697401,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
170,"Here}WR@dp@VE{z",0,"Here","1059      ","1059      ",75261,5768201,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
171,"Here}WR@LKAVdyDi",0,"Here","1059      ","1059      ",75261,5771401,"A       ","O"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
```

My Python Script Code:

```
import csv

filename = rb'./Converted Database/DB_After.csv'
start_skip_row = 15
stop_skip_row = 405061


def readCSVFile(file_name: str, start: int, stop: int) -> list:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file_content:
        data_after_deletion = [line.replace('\n', '') for idx, line in enumerate(file_content) if
                               not start - 1 <= idx < stop]
        print(data_after_deletion)
        return data_after_deletion


def writeCSVFile(data: list) -> None:
    with open('./Converted Database/DB_Compiled.KingAdamI', 'w', newline='') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerows(data)


data_after_deletion = readCSVFile(filename, start_skip_row, stop_skip_row)
writeCSVFile(data_after_deletion)
```

Do you have any ideas why after execution of this script, my structure of CSV has ben destroyed?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `csv.reader` or `csv.writer`. You can simply read the input csv file line by line and write those lines which are not in the range `[15, 405061]` to output csv file:

```
with open('./Converted Database/DB_After.csv') as f1,\
        open('./Converted Database/DB_Compiled.KingAdamI', 'w') as f2:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f1, 1):
        if idx < 15 or idx > 405061:
            f2.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

csvwriter acts as Dictwriter and expects the parameter passed to writerows() function to be an iterable of strings or numbers and a dictionary mapping fieldnames to strings or numbers.
In above code, since you are passing a list of strings, it has just iterated through every character and delimited with comma.
Changing this statement under readCSVFile()

```
data_after_deletion = [line.replace('\n', '') for idx, line in enumerate(file_content) if
                               not start - 1 <= idx < stop]
```

as below

```
data_after_deletion = [{line.replace('\n', '')} for idx, line in enumerate(file_content) if
                               not start - 1 <= idx < stop]
```

May help to retain the structure.